# Update different data type columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables GCB.NewsOne & GCB.NewsTwo both table are same except one column
it's GCode in `dbo.News` table `GCode` is `varchar(100) null` and `GCB.News` table has a `bigint null` column.

Now I want to update the code in `GCode` in `dbo.News` to the value of `GCB.News`.

I tried like below, but it's not working

```
UPDATE [GCB].[NewsOne] AS G
SET G.Code = (SELECT P.Code FROM GCB.NewsTwo P WHERE G.ID = P.ID)
```

Comment: *"but not working"* doesn't mean anything. Does it produce an error, unexpected results, causes your SQL Server to crash..?

Comment: @Larnu Incorrect syntax near G

Comment: You can't alias a table in the `UPDATE` clause; you can only alias them in the `FROM`. You can, however, reference the alias of a table in the `UPDATE` clause, as @TimBiegeleisen's answer demonstrates.

Comment: `SET G.Code = CAST(P.Code AS VARCHAR(MAX))`

Answer (score 2):

Try casting the bigint to varchar:

```
UPDATE G
SET Code = CAST(P.Code AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM [GCB].[NewsOne] G
INNER JOIN GCB.NewsTwo P
    ON G.ID = P.ID;
```

This assumes that your problem really is the types of the two codes, and not something else.

Also note that I rewrote your join using update join syntax, which I think is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You may not use an alias in an update statement. This works fine:

```
UPDATE [GCB].[NewsOne] 
SET [GCB].[NewsOne].Code = ( SELECT P.Code FROM GCB.NewsTwo P 
                              WHERE [GCB].[NewsOne].ID=P.ID )
```